# Is "then to do what" common/idiomatic?

Tags: idioms, phrase-usage

Example:

> Speaker A: “I’m not here to catch you.”
>
> Speaker B: “Then to do
>   what?”

I thought it was common phrase. But Google tells me the opposite.

If it's not common, what's a better alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I would expect here would be:

Speaker A: “I’m not here to catch you.”
Speaker B: “Then what *are* you here for?”

Comment: +1, though I would probably say ***why*** instead of ***what...for***.